# putting different groups in details section in crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am developing a **project on payroll** where I am having issues while putting two different groups in detail section.
What I am trying is printing something like this:

```
Earnings                    Deductions                 Recoveries

Basic Pay= 10000            Basic Pay= 10000           Basic Pay= 10000
DA=         8000            DA=         8000           DA=         8000
```

Here **Pay_Head_type=1 for Earnings, 2 for Deductions and 3 for Recoveries**. 
What I found is when I add the group in the **"Select Expert"** section it automatically make all to **Pay_Head_type=1**.

What I am trying to get will be like this:

```
 Earnings                    Deductions                 Recoveries

 Basic Pay= 10000            GPF= 6000                  Vehicle Advance= 2000
 DA=         8000            SPA= 2000
```

How can I assign different groups in **"Select Expert"** section so that I can get all different values, also I want to print sum of a particular column (for say **Pay_Head_type=1**) at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are filtering, but could you not just bring in the Pay_Head_Type 1 2 and 3, and sort them with formula?

calcDeductions

if Pay_Head_Type = 2 then
    value
else
    0

Do the same for 1 and 3, then you can sum these based on your groups on the report and get the values into the details section or group footers

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried it but it still showing the same results, is there any way to apply where conditions here

Comment: You are using the select expert to apply a where to the query as it is so I am not sure what you mean?